# Get foreground (font) in a particular JTable cell

Tags: java, swing, unit-testing, fonts

There are many answers to how to *set* the font (use renderer), but I want to *get* this font.  The reason why is for unit-testing: test for the renderer doing its job OK.

The human eye can see whether a component for a given cell is rendered with a red foreground, but how can we do this programmatically?

**later**
 Just a word about my comment "get hold of the screen real estate". That's not quite it: each one of these table cells contains something... but what? And is it possible to reference it? It almost seems that each one is the "ghost" of the component (the same one) used successively to render each individual cell. Obviously I don't really know about the "architecture" of the representation of a JTable. Would be interesting to find out... although I suspect strongly that these "ghosts" (or whatever) are inaccessible.

Comment: `each one of these table cells contains something... but what?` Each cell is just a painting of a component (which is referred to as the renderer).  `And is it possible to reference it?` - I already answered that. The table just repeatedly invokes the prepareRenderer(...) method for every cell it needs to paint. So if you want a real component, you can only ever get the state of a single cell one at a time by invoking the prepareRenderer() method manually.. There are no real components in any cell of the table. All cells are just paintings.

Comment: Just paintings... right.  Except cleverly done because, for example, you can select and copy text from them (without invoking the editor).  Again, if one could be bothered, one could get java.awt.Robot to select the text in question, by moving the mouse to the cell's rectangle ... but would it also be able to tell the foreground colour?  Of course it would then be selection highlighted... maybe the foreground would be available???  Yes, it's a bit academic!

Comment: The default copy functionality will copy an entire row of data. You can't just select a couple of character of text from the cell, unless you have custom functionality.

Comment: Oh, is that right?  OK.  Point taken.  No dice.  At all... prepareRenderer it is!

Comment: You don't need a Robot to select a cell. You just use the `changeSelection(...)` method of JTable. So you invoke that method before the prepareRenderer() method and you can get the foreground of the cell in any state that you want.

Comment: Yes... the only reason I was wondering about selecting was how you could actually hoover up that text with a view to examining its colour.  But as it's just a painting that's no good.  Plus, even if selection was possible it presumably wouldn't pick up attributes, only text.  My thinking was way off...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `JTable.prepareRenderer(...)` method.

This method will return the `Component` that will be used to do the rendering of the cell. So you can then invoke the `getForeground()` method on the `Component`.

Comment: Thanks.  I realise one could do that, but I was hoping for a more direct way: get hold of the screen real estate and somehow determine it from that.  My default renderer in fact renders certain cells' foregrounds different to others.  So one way to unit-test would be to submit different row, col and values to the renderer's getTableCellRendererComponent() method and check the foreground of the delivered component.  I suppose that's the best one can do, practically.

Comment: @mikerodent Well, you could just use `getCellRenderer` and pass it through `prepareRenderer` and use `getFont` from the resulting renderer

Comment: @MadProgrammer, `you could just use getCellRenderer and pass it through prepareRenderer` not sure what that means?  How is that different that what I suggested? Yes you need to get the `getCellRenderer()` since a renderer is a parameter of the `prepareRenderer()` method. I thought that would be obvious.

Comment: @camickr That was more of what I was suggesting, you need to "get" the renderer first.  Obviously, at that point, you can decide if you're going to pass it test data or pass it through `preapreRenderer`, I just added the need to actually "get the renderer" first

Comment: Yes, only prob with prepareRenderer is that you can't pass the value (or isSelected or hasFocus): these can of course influence the foreground you want.  But I'm sure you'd both have thought of that...

Comment: @mikerodent It comes down to your needs, but if use `getCellRenderer` first, you can then decide what to do with it, and pass what ever values you want to test to the `getTableCellRendererComponent`. It all comes down to what and how your testing ;)

Comment: `you can't pass the value (or isSelected or hasFocus` - the prepareRenderer() method will set up those values for you as it invokes the getTableCellRendererComponent(...) method. So it will return the "current" state of the cell (which is what I assumed you wanted). If you want all possible states of the cell, then you will need to invoke the cell renderer directly.